Troubleshooting Data Abort Error While Debugging U-Boot on mcimx6ul-evk in QEMU
I am trying to debug U-Boot code in Ubuntu 18.04 using the mcimx6ul-evk board in QEMU. I have successfully compiled QEMU (./configure --prefix=/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user --enable-debug  --enable-debug --python=/usr/bin/python3.7) and U-Boot（make mx6ull_14x14_evk_defconfig） using arm-linux-gnueabihf-. When I attempt to run U-Boot and debug it with GDB,
/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/qemu-system-arm \
    -M mcimx6ul-evk \
    -m 512M \
    -kernel /home/book/imx6ull/uboot-mx6ul/u-boot \
    -nographic \
    -d in_asm,cpu_reset,guest_errors,unimp \
 -D debug.log \
 -s -S 

I encounter an issue in the get_cpu_rev function:
struct scu_regs *scu = (struct scu_regs *)SCU_BASE_ADDR;
cfg = readl(&scu->config) & 3;

This triggers a data_abort error. The log displays
----------------

IN: get_cpu_rev

0x87802786:  

OBJD-T: 5968

  

Invalid read at addr 0xA00004, size 4, region '(null)', reason: rejected

----------------

Furthermore, I also tested a precompiled qemu-system-arm.exe in windows (the -version command shows the same 7.2.0 version of QEMU, although I'm not sure if there were any differences in the compilation process) to debug the same U-Boot code, and I did not encounter the data_abort error at the get_cpu_rev step. The log displays
----------------

IN: get_cpu_rev

0x87802786:

OBJD-T: 5968

scu: unimplemented device read  (size 4, offset 0x0004)

----------------

I wonder how the differences between these two situations arise?
PS. Here are the relevant commands and output from my environment:
./configure --prefix=/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user --enable-debug  --enable-debug --python=/usr/bin/python3.7
Using './build' as the directory for build output
The Meson build system
Version: 0.61.5
Source dir: /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0
Build dir: /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/build
Build type: native build
Project name: qemu
Project version: 7.2.0
C compiler for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.30
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program scripts/symlink-install-tree.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/symlink-install-tree.py)
Program sh found: YES (/bin/sh)
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7)
Program bzip2 found: YES (/bin/bzip2)
Program iasl found: NO
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,-z,relro: YES 
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,-z,now: YES 
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 7.5.0 "c++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.30
Compiler for C++ supports link arguments -Wl,--warn-common: YES 
Program cgcc found: NO
Library m found: YES
Run-time dependency threads found: YES
Library util found: YES
Run-time dependency appleframeworks found: NO (tried framework)
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Run-time dependency gio-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Program gdbus-codegen found: YES (/usr/bin/gdbus-codegen)
Run-time dependency gio-unix-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Run-time dependency pixman-1 found: YES 0.34.0
Run-time dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.11
Has header "libaio.h" : NO 
Run-time dependency liburing found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libnfs found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency appleframeworks found: NO (tried framework)
Run-time dependency appleframeworks found: NO (tried framework)
Run-time dependency libseccomp found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "cap-ng.h" : NO 
Run-time dependency xkbcommon found: YES 0.8.2
Run-time dependency slirp found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "libvdeplug.h" : NO 
Run-time dependency libpulse found: YES 11.1
Run-time dependency alsa found: YES 1.1.3
Run-time dependency jack found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency sndio found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency spice-protocol found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency spice-server found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Library rt found: YES
Run-time dependency libiscsi found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libzstd found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency virglrenderer found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency blkio found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libcurl found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libudev found: YES 237
Library mpathpersist found: NO
Run-time dependency ncursesw found: YES 6.1.20180127
Has header "brlapi.h" : NO 
Run-time dependency sdl2 found: YES 2.0.8
Run-time dependency sdl2_image found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Library rados found: NO
Has header "rbd/librbd.h" : NO 
Run-time dependency glusterfs-api found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libssh found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "bzlib.h" : NO 
Has header "lzfse.h" : NO 
Has header "sys/soundcard.h" : YES 
Run-time dependency epoxy found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "epoxy/egl.h" with dependency epoxy: NO 
Run-time dependency gnutls found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency gnutls found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
libgcrypt-config found: NO need ['>=1.8']
Run-time dependency libgcrypt found: NO (tried config-tool)
Run-time dependency nettle found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency gmp found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency gtk+-3.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libpng found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libjpeg found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "sasl/sasl.h" : NO 
Has header "security/pam_appl.h" : NO 
Has header "snappy-c.h" : NO 
Has header "lzo/lzo1x.h" : NO 
Has header "numa.h" : NO 
Library ibumad found: NO
Has header "rdma/rdma_cma.h" : NO 
Library ibverbs found: NO
Run-time dependency xencontrol found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Library xenstore found: NO
Library xenctrl found: NO
Library xendevicemodel found: NO
Library xenforeignmemory found: NO
Library xengnttab found: NO
Library xenevtchn found: NO
Library xentoolcore found: NO
Run-time dependency libcacard found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency u2f-emu found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency canokey-qemu found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libusbredirparser-0.5 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libusb-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libpmem found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libdaxctl found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libkeyutils found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Checking for function "gettid" : NO 
Run-time dependency libselinux found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency fuse3 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Run-time dependency libbpf found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Has header "sys/epoll.h" : YES 
Has header "linux/magic.h" : YES 
Has header "valgrind/valgrind.h" : NO 
Has header "linux/btrfs.h" : YES 
Has header "libdrm/drm.h" : YES 
Has header "pty.h" : YES 
Has header "sys/disk.h" : NO 
Has header "sys/ioccom.h" : NO 
Has header "sys/kcov.h" : NO 
Checking for function "close_range" : NO 
Checking for function "accept4" : YES 
Checking for function "clock_adjtime" : YES 
Checking for function "dup3" : YES 
Checking for function "fallocate" : YES 
Checking for function "posix_fallocate" : YES 
Checking for function "posix_memalign" : YES 
Checking for function "_aligned_malloc" : NO 
Checking for function "valloc" : YES 
Checking for function "memalign" : YES 
Checking for function "ppoll" : YES 
Checking for function "preadv" : YES 
Checking for function "pthread_fchdir_np" : NO 
Checking for function "sendfile" : YES 
Checking for function "setns" : YES 
Checking for function "unshare" : YES 
Checking for function "syncfs" : YES 
Checking for function "sync_file_range" : YES 
Checking for function "timerfd_create" : YES 
Checking for function "copy_file_range" : YES 
Checking for function "getifaddrs" : YES 
Checking for function "openpty" with dependency -lutil: YES 
Checking for function "strchrnul" : YES 
Checking for function "system" : YES 
Header <byteswap.h> has symbol "bswap_32" : YES 
Header <sys/epoll.h> has symbol "epoll_create1" : YES 
Header <linux/falloc.h> has symbol "FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE" : YES 
Header <linux/falloc.h> has symbol "FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE" : YES 
Header <linux/falloc.h> has symbol "FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE" : YES 
Has header "linux/fiemap.h" : YES 
Header <linux/fs.h> has symbol "FS_IOC_FIEMAP" : YES 
Checking for function "getrandom" : YES 
Header <sys/random.h> has symbol "GRND_NONBLOCK" : YES 
Header <sys/inotify.h> has symbol "inotify_init" : YES 
Header <sys/inotify.h> has symbol "inotify_init1" : YES 
Header <machine/bswap.h> has symbol "bswap32" : NO 
Header <sys/prctl.h> has symbol "PR_SET_TIMERSLACK" : YES 
Header <linux/rtnetlink.h> has symbol "IFLA_PROTO_DOWN" : YES 
Header <sys/sysmacros.h> has symbol "makedev" : YES 
Header <getopt.h> has symbol "optreset" : NO 
Header <netinet/in.h> has symbol "IPPROTO_MPTCP" : NO 
Header <sys/mount.h> has symbol "FSCONFIG_SET_FLAG" : NO 
Checking whether type "struct sigevent" has member "sigev_notify_thread_id" : NO 
Checking whether type "struct stat" has member "st_atim" : YES 
Checking for type "struct iovec" : YES 
Checking for type "struct utmpx" : YES 
Checking for type "struct mmsghdr" : YES 
Header <linux/vm_sockets.h> has symbol "AF_VSOCK" : YES 
Program scripts/minikconf.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/minikconf.py)
Configuring arm-softmmu-config-target.h using configuration
Configuring arm-softmmu-config-devices.mak with command
Reading depfile: /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/build/meson-private/arm-softmmu-config-devices.mak.d
Configuring arm-softmmu-config-devices.h using configuration
Configuring arm-linux-user-config-target.h using configuration
Program scripts/make-config-poison.sh found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/make-config-poison.sh)
Run-time dependency capstone found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Library fdt found: NO
Configuring config-host.h using configuration
Program scripts/hxtool found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/hxtool)
Program scripts/shaderinclude.pl found: YES (/usr/bin/env perl /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/shaderinclude.pl)
Program scripts/qapi-gen.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/qapi-gen.py)
Program scripts/qemu-version.sh found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/qemu-version.sh)

Executing subproject libvhost-user 

libvhost-user| Project name: libvhost-user
libvhost-user| Project version: undefined
libvhost-user| C compiler for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")
libvhost-user| C linker for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.30
libvhost-user| Dependency threads found: YES unknown (cached)
libvhost-user| Dependency glib-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4 (overridden)
libvhost-user| Build targets in project: 10
libvhost-user| Subproject libvhost-user finished.


Executing subproject libvduse 

libvduse| Project name: libvduse
libvduse| Project version: undefined
libvduse| C compiler for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")
libvduse| C linker for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.30
libvduse| Build targets in project: 11
libvduse| Subproject libvduse finished.

Program scripts/decodetree.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/decodetree.py)
Program ../scripts/modules/module_block.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/block/../scripts/modules/module_block.py)
Program ../scripts/block-coroutine-wrapper.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/block/../scripts/block-coroutine-wrapper.py)
Program scripts/modinfo-collect.py found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/modinfo-collect.py)
Program scripts/modinfo-generate.py found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/modinfo-generate.py)
Program nm found: YES
Program scripts/undefsym.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/undefsym.py)
Program scripts/feature_to_c.sh found: YES (/bin/sh /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/feature_to_c.sh)
Configuring 50-edk2-i386-secure.json using configuration
Configuring 50-edk2-x86_64-secure.json using configuration
Configuring 60-edk2-aarch64.json using configuration
Configuring 60-edk2-arm.json using configuration
Configuring 60-edk2-i386.json using configuration
Configuring 60-edk2-x86_64.json using configuration
Program qemu-keymap found: NO
Program sphinx-build-3 sphinx-build found: NO
Program bash found: YES 4.4.20 (/bin/bash)
Program diff found: YES (/usr/bin/diff)
Program dbus-daemon found: YES (/usr/bin/dbus-daemon)
Did not find CMake 'cmake'
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency gvnc-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Program initrd-stress.sh found: YES (/home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/tests/migration/initrd-stress.sh)
Build targets in project: 492

qemu 7.2.0

  Directories
    Install prefix               : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build
    BIOS directory               : share/qemu
    firmware path                : share/qemu-firmware
    binary directory             : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/bin
    library directory            : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    module directory             : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qemu
    libexec directory            : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/libexec
    include directory            : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/include
    config directory             : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/etc
    local state directory        : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/var
    Manual directory             : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/share/man
    Doc directory                : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build/share/doc
    Build directory              : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/build
    Source path                  : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0
    GIT submodules               : ui/keycodemapdb tests/fp/berkeley-testfloat-3 tests/fp/berkeley-softfloat-3 dtc

  Host binaries
    git                          : git
    make                         : make
    python                       : /usr/bin/python3.7 (version: 3.7)
    sphinx-build                 : NO
    iasl                         : NO
    genisoimage                  : /usr/bin/genisoimage

  Configurable features
    Documentation                : NO
    system-mode emulation        : YES
    user-mode emulation          : YES
    block layer                  : YES
    Install blobs                : YES
    module support               : NO
    fuzzing support              : NO
    Audio drivers                : pa oss
    Trace backends               : log
    D-Bus display                : NO
    QOM debugging                : NO
    vhost-kernel support         : YES
    vhost-net support            : YES
    vhost-user support           : YES
    vhost-user-crypto support    : YES
    vhost-user-blk server support: YES
    vhost-vdpa support           : YES
    build guest agent            : YES

  Compilation
    host CPU                     : x86_64
    host endianness              : little
    C compiler                   : cc -m64 -mcx16
    Host C compiler              : cc -m64 -mcx16
    C++ compiler                 : c++ -m64 -mcx16
    CFLAGS                       : -O0 -g
    CXXFLAGS                     : -O0 -g
    QEMU_CFLAGS                  : -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong
    QEMU_CXXFLAGS                : -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong
    QEMU_OBJCFLAGS               : 
    QEMU_LDFLAGS                 : -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-common
    profiler                     : NO
    link-time optimization (LTO) : NO
    PIE                          : YES
    static build                 : NO
    malloc trim support          : YES
    membarrier                   : NO
    debug stack usage            : NO
    mutex debugging              : YES
    memory allocator             : system
    avx2 optimization            : YES
    avx512f optimization         : NO
    gprof enabled                : NO
    gcov                         : NO
    thread sanitizer             : NO
    CFI support                  : NO
    strip binaries               : NO
    sparse                       : NO
    mingw32 support              : NO

  Targets and accelerators
    KVM support                  : NO
    HAX support                  : NO
    HVF support                  : NO
    WHPX support                 : NO
    NVMM support                 : NO
    Xen support                  : NO
    TCG support                  : YES
    TCG backend                  : native (x86_64)
    TCG plugins                  : YES
    TCG debug enabled            : YES
    target list                  : arm-softmmu arm-linux-user
    default devices              : YES
    out of process emulation     : YES
    vfio-user server             : NO

  Block layer support
    coroutine backend            : ucontext
    coroutine pool               : YES
    Block whitelist (rw)         : 
    Block whitelist (ro)         : 
    Use block whitelist in tools : NO
    VirtFS support               : NO
    build virtiofs daemon        : NO
    Live block migration         : YES
    replication support          : YES
    bochs support                : YES
    cloop support                : YES
    dmg support                  : YES
    qcow v1 support              : YES
    vdi support                  : YES
    vvfat support                : YES
    qed support                  : YES
    parallels support            : YES
    FUSE exports                 : NO
    VDUSE block exports          : YES

  Crypto
    TLS priority                 : NORMAL
    GNUTLS support               : NO
    libgcrypt                    : NO
    nettle                       : NO
    AF_ALG support               : NO
    rng-none                     : NO
    Linux keyring                : YES

  Dependencies
    SDL support                  : YES
    SDL image support            : NO
    GTK support                  : NO
    pixman                       : YES 0.34.0
    VTE support                  : NO
    slirp support                : NO
    libtasn1                     : NO
    PAM                          : NO
    iconv support                : YES
    curses support               : YES
    virgl support                : NO
    blkio support                : NO
    curl support                 : NO
    Multipath support            : NO
    PNG support                  : NO
    VNC support                  : YES
    VNC SASL support             : NO
    VNC JPEG support             : NO
    OSS support                  : YES
    sndio support                : NO
    ALSA support                 : YES 1.1.3
    PulseAudio support           : YES 11.1
    JACK support                 : NO
    brlapi support               : NO
    vde support                  : NO
    netmap support               : NO
    l2tpv3 support               : YES
    Linux AIO support            : NO
    Linux io_uring support       : NO
    ATTR/XATTR support           : YES
    RDMA support                 : NO
    PVRDMA support               : NO
    fdt support                  : internal
    libcap-ng support            : NO
    bpf support                  : NO
    spice protocol support       : NO
    rbd support                  : NO
    smartcard support            : NO
    U2F support                  : NO
    libusb                       : NO
    usb net redir                : NO
    OpenGL support (epoxy)       : NO
    GBM                          : NO
    libiscsi support             : NO
    libnfs support               : NO
    seccomp support              : NO
    GlusterFS support            : NO
    TPM support                  : YES
    libssh support               : NO
    lzo support                  : NO
    snappy support               : NO
    bzip2 support                : NO
    lzfse support                : NO
    zstd support                 : NO
    NUMA host support            : NO
    capstone                     : NO
    libpmem support              : NO
    libdaxctl support            : NO
    libudev                      : YES 237
    FUSE lseek                   : NO
    selinux                      : NO

  Subprojects
    libvduse                     : YES
    libvhost-user                : YES

  User defined options
    Native files                 : config-meson.cross
    optimization                 : 0
    prefix                       : /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0_build
    debug_mutex                  : true
    vfio_user_server             : disabled

Found ninja-1.8.2 at /usr/bin/ninja
Running postconf script '/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/book/qemu/qemu-7.2.0/scripts/symlink-install-tree.py'

PSS.I've tested multiple versions of QEMU (7.2.0/4.1.1) and U-Boot (u-boot-fslc-2016.05/u-boot-fslc-2023.10/uboot-imx-rel_imx_4.1.15_2.1.0_ga). When I run qemu-system-arm -M help, the Supported machines list includes mcimx6ul-evk.
